# How to compute $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Im not sure how to do this. What's the answer to

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}$$
Im not sure if i have to use another function in order to get some terms out of the summation or something like that

Comment: What is $(1+1)^n$?

Comment: @Jack but why 2^n im not sure why i completely forgot

Comment: Do you know how to expand $(a+b)^n$?

Comment: @Jack ohh newtons !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}1^k1^{n-k}
$$

Comment: binomiale but doesnt it give u 1 at the end if u sum the probabilities of the binomial knowing $\Bbb P(X=k)=\binom {n}{k}1^k1^{n-k}$

Comment: thank you for the answet guys but @Jack how come when u sum a binomiale it gives u $2^n$ and not just 1

Comment: @user387171 but this summation here doesn't add up to 1, it adds up to $2^n $ as well.

Comment: @RSerrao ik that but how ?

Comment: @RSerrao ik that but how ? i was asking myself if it was because of the k=0 that it gives us $ (1+1)^n $

Comment: @user387171 yup it follows from the expansion of $(1+1)^n $ using the Binomial Theorem

Comment: @RSerrao thank you fir ur answers

Comment: @user387171 : You are mistaken if you think this is a sum of probabilities. It is not. "Binomial" doesn't mean "binomial distribution", it means "(power of) two-term polynomial". In fact, this sum is always an integer.